# Using Appkit and Python to hide mouse cursor on OSX

Tags: python, macos, appkit, pyobjc

I'm trying to script hiding the mouse cursor on OSX 10.9.  I have Chrome starting and going full screen for a kiosk and I'd like to periodically run a script to hide the cursor.

Applescript no longer directly supports "call method" to call the objective C method, so I thought the simplest method would be to use AppKit from the provided python.

It crashes:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import AppKit
>>> AppKit.NSCursor.hide()
Assertion failed: (CGAtomicGet(&is_initialized)), function CGSConnectionByID, file Services/Connection/CGSConnection.c, line 123.
Abort trap: 6
```

I suspect there is a pre-requisite call I need to make to initialize *something*,  but I haven't found anything yet while digging through docs/google.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with the Quartz included with [PyObjC](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/):

```
import Quartz
Quartz.CGDisplayHideCursor(Quartz.CGMainDisplayID())
```

Comment: I ssh'ed in and tried it -- it ran, but didn't change the cursor.  Next step is to try it as part of the cron job that updates the kiosk.

Comment: On the other hand, I can now call AppKit.NSCursor.hide() after I call the Quartz function, so it initializes something that needed initializing.  But the cursor still is viewable!

Comment: I tried running this from the interactive shell and it didn't do anything.